# При изменении позиции в аниматоре она меняется на сцене в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть монетка, у нее есть анимация подскока, но когда анимация начинается монетка телепортируется на нулевые координаты.

Дело в том ,что я изменял позицию монетки в анимации для создания нужного эфекта, и она телепортировалась на координаты которые я указал в анимации.

как это можно обойти?

Comment: Изменяй локальную позицию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самый простой способ это запихнуть монетку в пустой объект и передвигать пустой объект, тогда анимация тогда у монетки должа работать правильно